# cordova prepare not add plugins to iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building mobile app with Cordova 5.3.3.
I've add plugins with `cordova plugin add some.plugin --save` and add platform using `cordova plugin add ios --save`

The problem is if I completely remove `rm -rf platform/ios` and then run `cordova prepare` the resulting Xcode proejct does not have anything in the `Plugins` directory.

The only was I found to solve this is to remove and re-add the plugins but that's seem like the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the plugins, you should do it before `cordova prepare`. Use `cordoba platform add ios`and it should work

Comment: but the whole point of using `cordova platform add ios --save` is that `cordova prepare` should restore everything automatically